# how do i get multiple inner joins in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

the problem is that in the table contact a contact can be linked to 4 companies
and i want to display all the companies a contact is linked to.
The first inner join works fine but i want to add 3 more inner join but i dont know how to do this with sql server because my experience is with MySql
this is what i have so far:

```
select contact.Contact_id, 
       contact.Firstname,
       contact.Abbreviation,
       company.Company,
       company.Company,
       company.Company,
       company.Company,
       contact.Sector,
       contact.Available
FROM contact
INNER JOIN company 
  ON  contact.Company_id1=company.Company_id
  WHERE available =1
  ORDER BY Firstname ASC
```

Comment: You would add additional inner joins EXACTLY the same way you would in MySql.

Comment: Why does the php tag keep getting added? This has NOTHING to do with php.

Comment: I see the words "can be linked to 4 companies".  This indicates that you need to use outer joins instead of inner joins.  So you would outer join from the contact to company 4 times (aliased company, company2, company3, company4, for example).  table structures would be helpful.

Comment: Do you really have columns names Company_id1 etc? You should consider normalization. What happens when business decides they need 5? You either can't support it or you have to change the table and every query that touches it.

Comment: @SeanLange i did that but i get error "The objects "company" and "company" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them."

Comment: MySql would be the same. You have to provide an alias that is unique. Maybe company1, company2 etc...

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
select <columns>
from contact as ct
join company as cy1 on cy1.company_id = ct.company_id1
join company as cy2 on cy2.company_id = ct.company_id2
join company as cy3 on cy3.company_id = ct.company_id2
join company as cy4 on cy4.company_id = ct.company_id4
```

Comment: I'd make those left joins, personally, for the case in which the contact is not affiliated with any  companies or some variant between all and none.

Comment: Yes, there are better ways. I just want to give him an idea about what can be done.

Comment: @GabrielBSM it works ish the problem ive been dealing with using this method is i only get the last row as a result in my table here some proof:[link](http://imgur.com/a/XlygG)